# Query firebase objects by user

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I have a data structure that looks like:

```
{
  "farms" : {
    "-J3saHfe8_2GRqn3jOTc" : {
      "stockunits" : {
        "-J4CAeRI-IKKXVuNILCv" : {
          "name" : "Chickens",
          "totalStockUnits" : 115
        }
      },
      "owner" : 3,
      "name" : "smith"
    },
    "-J3sbbqsGabs5cLaj0zP" : {
      "owner" : 2,
      "name" : "brown"
    }
  }
}
```

When I query "/farms" I would like to get a list of the farms for which the authenticated user is the owner. I would also like to prevent users from viewing farms that they are not the owner for.

My rules currently look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".write": false,
  ".read": false,
  "farms": {
    "$farm": {
        ".read": "data.child('owner').val() == auth.id"
```

I get that by putting the .read at this level I am granting read access to individual farm when accessed via /farms/:farmid. And if I move the ".read" up to the "farms" level this results in granting read access to the entire list.

So I think I need to restructure my data but aren't sure how best to go about this? I don't want to add the farms object below the user object as I will be wanting to add a number of "editor" users to any given farm as well.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to denormalize your data and include references to individual farm objects under each user's profile. There's a full example of how to do this kind of denormalization in this blog post: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html

In that example, the code snippets show organizing comments under posts, you can use a similar technique to map farms to users.

Comment: De-normalizing works fine but getting set of objects for a user into your scope collection isn't currently supported by AngularFire.
In order to do so you also need the experimental branch of AngularFire as discussed here: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/92